# Pattern for updating the only "active" item of a list?

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

Let's say you have 4 elements and only one of them can have class `active`. The active element is updated a few times per second (here it's a dummy example in the snippet).

A naive way is to do:

- remove `active` from every element
- set `active` to the currently chosen element

The problem is that if the chosen element *hasn't changed*, we are removing the class, and *resetting* it again (which can cause display glitch), which is useless.

Of course we could add another rule to not remove if it's still the chosen one, but the code would become less readable.

Question: **is there a standard pattern to do this?**

```js
var i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    document.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
    document.querySelector('#item' + Math.floor(i /4)).classList.add('active');
}, 500);
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="item0" class="active">item 0</div>
<div id="item1">item 1</div>
<div id="item2">item 2</div>
<div id="item3">item 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Recap

So it sounds like you you are looking for a more *elegant* way of adding and removing an `active` class to a set of elements. Rather than removing the `active` class from all elements and then adding it back to the currently active element (*which can cause potential issues/visual glitches*). And it seems like you are trying to avoid adding too much code to check whether or not the `active` class needs to be removed/added (*in the event that active element has not changed*).

### Potential Solution

Personally, I don't think this is the *best* way of doing this (*using the ternary operator for code execution can be messy*), but I think the code is simple enough and fairly readable overall.

Essentially, you can merge the code to add or remove the `active` class. The `add()` function will only add a class if it is currently not on the element, and the opposite applies to the `remove()` function (only removing a class if it exists). This means you can call the `add()` function on the active element and not worry about it causing any visual glitches if the active element has not changed.

Using this logic, we just need to loop through all *possible* elements and then using the **ternary** operator, we can check to see if an element is the currently active one. If so, call `add()` (*which won't matter if the active element did not change*), otherwise, call `remove()`.

```js
let i = 0,
    interval;

interval = setInterval(() => {
  i += 1;
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^=item]").forEach(el => (el.id == `item${Math.floor(i / 4)}`) ? el.classList.add("active") : el.classList.remove("active"));
  if(i >= 24) clearInterval(interval);
}, 500);
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="item0" class="active">item 0</div>
<div id="item1">item 1</div>
<div id="item2">item 2</div>
<div id="item3">item 3</div>
<div id="item4">item 4</div>
<div id="item5">item 5</div>
<div id="item6">item 6</div>
```

### Notes

This does assume you can loop through all *possible* active elements. In this situation they all have an `id` that starts with `item`. If there is no identifier that can be used to loop through all possible active elements, it adds a bit more code.

Answer (score 1):

*There's no need to improve your code*, because style rendering are blocked when JavaScript are executing. No glitches can be seen as the "intermediate" DOM won't be shown. You can try the following snippet:

```js
window.setTimeout(function () {
    let eles = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    eles[0].classList.remove("active");
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100_000; i++) {
        eles[0].textContent = String(i);
    }
    eles[1].classList.add("active");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="active">1</p>
<p>2</p>
```

Comment: *"style rendering are blocked when JavaScript are executing. No glitches can be seen as the "intermediate" DOM won't be shown"*: great! Are you 100% sure, do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I believe I have seen an article about it on MDN, but unfortunately I forgot its title and failed to find. :( But you can refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) which implies synchronous JavaScript can block rendering.

Comment: @Basj Though not being the one I saw before, [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread) mentioned the reason.